# FullCalendar Week view but horizontal

Tags: layout, fullcalendar

I am in need displaying the dayGridWeek but horizontal in rows, not columns. Imagine the list view but showing every day of the week regardless of whether it's filled or not.

[image]

It seems I can create a customView but can I tell FullCalendar to render the whole week the way it does it in dayGridWeek and let me style this?

Comment: With a custom view you can do pretty much anything you like. You just have to figure out how to make it happen

Comment: Is there a method to display 7 days regardless of whether they have events in them?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean? The dayGrid, timeGrid and timeline views already all display a set of consecutive dates, regardless of whether events exist in those days or not. Only the list view does not do that.

Comment: That's why I put the graphic up. These views are alright but I need to have them horizontal. Right now I can have horizontal view but without empty days OR normal consecutive days but with vertical view. 

What would be a sample dayGridWeek custom view, e.g. showing only the titles?

Comment: "need"? Or "want"? Sounds like you would tolerate the existing views if you had to. Making a completely custom view like this is possible but it's not simple, even if you start by cloning one of the existing ones from the source code. In fact it's probably reasonably complex. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js gives you the bare bones of how you start, but then there's a lot of work to do.

Comment: That's exactly my question "How to show a custom view?". Thanks for letting me know it's more complex, I thought I might have just missed something small. There should be an option to display empty days in any view if you need I think.

Comment: Visit https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features if you want to make suggestions to the people who maintain fullCalendar